# How to measure positive, negative and inbetween currents

Tags: power-supply, lm317

I am making a variable +12V / -12V bench power supply, where I will have 3 output pins: 0- -12VDC | GND | 0- +12VDC, where I want to measure all possible voltages and currents.
I will use voltmeters to measure potentials between: -12V and GND, GND and +12V, -12V and +12V; but I got stuck here, how to measure same currents.

I want to be shown at all time the current between GND and -12V, -12V and +12V & GND and +12V, but don't know how to wire the ammeters here.

[image]
Red resistor is between 0 and +12V;
Blue resistor is between 0 and -12V;
Black resistor is between -12V and +12V.

Comment: How do you *think* you should wire the ammeters? Also, I'd appreciate a simple schematic so we can all agree on the topology.

Comment: Ofcourse I should wire ammeter in series, but I'm confused how to wire an ammeter on the GND pin, because the current can flow into the GND or out of the GND pin.

Comment: @Jakey See my answer

Comment: @HarrySvensson: Edited.

Comment: @Jakey I'm happy that I made my first comment. You showing some effort definitely goes a long way (earned a +1 from me). The solution is very simple, but I'll let Decapod solve it (or someone else). He'll know how to answer this question flawlessly.

Comment: @HarrySvensson: Yes, thank you.
But here's one thing, that doesn't work very well: The ammeter on the GND line. I am using a digital ammeter, so I can't just add it there, because sometimes the current will flow into the GND and sometimes from the GND (depends between which pins the load will be connected vs. GND).
Is there anyhow I could measure the actual current flow on the GND line?

Comment: @Jakey Well you will measure the +12 V rail and -12 V rail, right? Let's say you measure 10 mA coming out of the 12 V rail and -4 mA coming out of the -12 V rail (=4 mA coming in to 12 V rail), what is the GND current? Since all currents have to sum up we know that out of the 10 mA from the +12 V, 4 mA of these will go to the -12 V rail. This leaves us with 6 mA going in to the GND. Another scenario: you measure 10 mA going out from 12 V and 20 mA going in  to -12 V, what is the GND current? Well out of the 20 mA, 10 will be coming from the 12 V rail, this means that the GND will supply 10mA

Comment: Exactly. And how to measure that current without calculating each time? I just want to simplify the readings while still planning the power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the voltmeters you need to connect them between +12V and GND and -12V and GND.
The ampere meters you should connect them in series with the outgoing +12V and the connector and the same for the -12V and the outgoing connector. If the power supplies are separated ( missing information!) then you could also place the ampere meters in both GND lines and combine the output on the connector.

In the situation that you are only interested in the differential current in the GND connection then you connect the two GND connections before the outgoing terminal. The ampere meter should in that case come between the two ground connections and the outgoing terminal.Depending on the load the current could be sourcing or sinking.

If you are using digital volt/amperemeters you should be carefull. For most units there is no galvanic separation between the supply and the measuring connection. In that case you might end up with separate supplies for each meter or at least for two of them. For the amperemeter in a common GND situation you need to select a type that can handle both positive and negative current. Not all types can.

Comment: Sorry, the power supplies are separated, yes.
And yes, I am using digital ammeter/voltmeters, that's the main reason, I'm asking.
I will use regular 12VDC power supply voltage voltmeters, but will power them with -12V for minus and GND for plus (for the -12V -> GND). That's the easiest way to measure the negative voltage. But I'm still concerned about the ammeter on the GND pin - it won't show correct, whether I'm having the red or blue resistor.

Comment: If the power supplies are separated then please show that in your diagram. Then you will see that there are 2 GND lines going to your powersupplies. Therefore two lines to put your ampere meter. You show a powersupply with +12V and -12V and a common GND

Comment: No. This is totally missunderstood now.
Inside the box, there will be 2 separated power supplies , but will have a common GND. And I want to measure the current flow on the GND line, but has to be independant of current flow direction. For analog instruments, that wouldn't be such a problem, but for digital is.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection of the ammeters and shunts is incorrect.

[image]

*Figure 1. Correct wiring of ammeter shunt in series with load - not across the supply rails.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foJNGF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Ammeter and voltmeter layout.*

Since you want to measure the current in the common rail you have no option but to add the ammeter in series with this. This has the disadvantage that your ground voltage will shift with current. You will have to determine whether or not this is acceptable.

The layout gives an interesting design decision requirement. Which current flow direction should be reported as positive? I suggest that you connect ammeter positive terminals to the PSU outputs. This will allow you to clearly monitor the current *out* of the terminal. The -12 ammeter will always display a negative value as it is only capable of sinking current. The common ammeter will indicate positive when sourcing current for the negative supply and negative when sinking current from the positive. When +12 and -12 loads are balanced the common ammeter will read zero.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I got stuck at the ammeter on the GND pin. I understood everything before, wasn't a problem for me. Voltmeters aren't a problem here, the ammeters are.
I thought of using 3 ammeters, as I've mentioned before, for the -12V -> GND, GND -> +12V and -12V -> +12V, but I just got an idea for solution with only 2 ammeters:
I should wire ammeters only to -12V and +12V lines, because that's what really matter to me: 
If only red resistor is applied, the -12V ammeter will show nothing, while the +12V ammeter will show current.

Comment: Opposite will happen if only blue resistor is connected.
But if I will connect a resistor between -12V and +12V, the both ammeters (-12V and +12V) will show (or at least should) show the same.
Is this a proper way to do it?
Should I add another ammeter only to measure the sum of all currents going in/out of GND?

Comment: The ammeter shunts must be placed in series with the output lines as indicated by the ammeters in my schematic. Your schematic and description is incorrect. You are showing the shunt resistors *across* the lines. That will cause a short-circuit.

Comment: @Jakey: See the update.

Comment: no no no, red, black and blue resistors aren't shunt resistors, they are burden to the shortcut. They will be BLDC motors etc.

Comment: "*... they are burden to the shortcut*" does not make sense to me. You need to fix your question, I think.

Comment: circuit*
I'm sorry, english is not my native language and sometimes in haste I switch simmilar words.

Comment: OK. Two ammeters should be enough. There is an error in your diagram. The RED circuit has both wires connected to GND.

Comment: PS: What about that ammeter on GND line you've showed? If it's analog, it works, but what if it's digital?

Comment: I don't know. You didn't supply a description, part number or datasheet link.

Comment: It's classical ammeter from worlds largest store on the web.

Answer (score 1):

As +12v, -12v and GND currents all sum to zero, use a sense resistor in the two 12v lines, sense these with differential input amplifiers, and use these voltages to represent your line currents. Then take the difference of these for the GND current.

The type of error you'd see in the GND current indication differs between a three sense resistor and my two sense resistor scheme, but both schemes will have errors, and the error will improve with matching components, so that's not really a significant differentiator between the methods.